# calling a function with an argument 'self' in main block

Tags: python

How to call this function in main:

```
def multiples(self):
     for i in range(5):
        print 3*i


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiples(what argument to pass here?)
```

Comment: Is `multiples` a method of a class?

Comment: It looks like you need to review how classes work in python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=class.

Comment: No its not part of a class. Its just an independent method.

Comment: appreciate everyone's quick response here. Thaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function isn't a member of a class, there is no reason for it to take a `self` argument (which it doesn't use anyway):

```
def multiples():
     for i in range(5):
        print 3*i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiples()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function definition that takes `self` as a parameter, *and that function definition is outside the scope of a class*, the `self` parameter has no special meaning -- it's just a normal argument. In your case, the function doesn't use the argument at all so it would be better to redefine your function rather than to pass in a value that won't be used:

```
def multiples():
    for i in range(5):
        print 3*i
```